# GetType() by last Control type

Tags: winforms, controls, gettype

I know, its a simple one. I want to get the type of the control in Winforms form.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Name = "btnLoadForm";
btn.Text = "Click to Load Form";
MessageBox.Show(btn.GetType().ToString());
```

It gives the output as `System.Windows.Forms.Button`, but I want simply want `Button`. I know its simple, but not sure how to find it on google. I will really appreciate if the we avoid splitting of strings for this. Any pointers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Name property instead, it will give you just the type name, without the namespace:

```
Button btn = new Button();
MessageBox.Show(btn.GetType().Name);
```

Comment: if we already have name set to something, is there  alternative way too to achieve this?? btw you have already solved my problem, i am just looking for some more good answers like yours...get ready for 15 reps :-) ...LOL

Comment: Hmm.. you get the name of your type, not of the button. For the latter use just btn.Name, without GetType()

Comment: But then I will get "Load Form" thats the name of the control but not "Button" thats type of the control, which I want.

Comment: I am perplexed now. How can you "set to something" the name of your type??

Comment: So? Your type is still Button :)

Comment: Oh My My!! I misunderstood it, sorry for eating your brain for no reason....thanks a lot